# Where do you find the "back" triangle button for UIToolBar?

Tags: ios, uitoolbar

Does anyone know where I can find the back triangle button for the UIButton. I need it for a in app webbrowser. Here's what I've got so far, but it looks wrong using the rewind button. I'm using interface builder on this view and if I could get the proper png I could set the UIBarButton image. I stumbled on the file path to access the SDKs private artwork but I've since lost it, I imagine it would be in there.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Deddiekoel is right. The back button is not included in the default images for a UIToolbarItem. There are two possibilities on achieving this.

1) Create your own image with a triangle in it. (simple way)

2) Subclass UIToolbarItem and override the `drawInRect:` method to draw your triangle with CoreGraphics Calls. (Harder but it's resizeable)

I didn't try the second way myself, but it should work because I did similar things with other objects. ;-)

Sandro Meier